# Failed to build latest netty snapshot

Tags: netty

Don't know if this is the best place for my question, but I'll ask here anyway.

I've checked out the latest content from the github url, but when I try to build netty it fails.

When I execute the mvn package statement (from the top-level directory) I get the following error:

> > [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.8:check (check-style) on project netty-parent: Execution check-style of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.8:check failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find io.netty:netty-build:jar:3 in https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss-public-repository-group has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

I'm not very good with maven, but I noticed it was missing the netty-build jar, so I checked out the netty-build project from github as well, successfully built it, and attempted to build netty again without any luck (same error message).

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
mvn [commands] -Dcheckstyle.skip
```

Answer (score 0):

It should build with :

## mvn clean package

Let me know if that does not work out

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work either.  I get the same error.  I noticed this as well from the output `[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.8:check (check-style) @ netty-parent ---
[WARNING] The POM for io.netty:netty-build:jar:3 is missing, no dependency information available`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to my experience, I delete that artifact from my local repository and let the Maven to re-download it again. I'm not sure what the root cause is. It may be the internet problem so that the artifact may not be completed.

I hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Netty requires some artifacts that is not available in the central Maven repository, So,

- First you must ensure your settings.xml in $HOME/.m2 directory that contains configuration as following xml, see [Netty Developers](http://www.jboss.org/netty/developers.html).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>jboss-nexus</id>
      <repositories>

        <repository>
          <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
          <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
          <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>

          <layout>default</layout>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>

          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>

        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>

          <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
          <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>

          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>

      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>jboss-nexus</activeProfile>    
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

- Second, It is still missing netty-build.jar file in JBoss maven repository, You can manual install in your local repository ($HOME/.m2/repository).

`git clone git://github.com/netty/netty-build.git`

`git checkout netty-build-3`

`mvn install`

- After all, you can build easily with `mvn package` command on top directory of netty project.

Comment: We are not part of JBoss.org anymore and our build depends only on the artifacts available in the central repo.  Our new web site is: http://netty.io/

Answer (score 0):

The missing artifact is now in the central repository.  It should build OK now.  You don't need to specify any additional 3rd party repositories in your `~/.m2/settings.xml`.  Please let me know if it does not build yet.

Comment: It doesn't built with commit `59e5f2f2623a0bb4af8012bc18aef3a47bb9704c`. Here the paste http://paste.dennis-boldt.de/2012/stackoverflow.com/netty_build_error -- but is not the `maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin` error any more.

Comment: What is your JDK version?  You might need to upgrade.

Comment: The version is 1.6.0_24. Is it to old/buggy?

Comment: Mine is 1.6.0_29 and it compiles fine.  Perhaps you need to upgrade to use the fixed compiler.

Comment: I did not upgrade my Java until now, but the actual version `549546f944a6cdb0cfe03b1d7fa8aad0dafd7e15` compiles in my terminal. In eclipse I am gettng still the error `Description Resource Path Location Type
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.8:check (execution: check-style, phase: validate) pom.xml /netty line 20 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem`

Comment: Could you pull again from the upstream and build again?  The M2E problem should be fixed now.

Comment: This `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle` is quite annoying, also in other projects. But you solved it. Good job. Thanks.